# TS2531 Object possibly 'null' despite check within for loop

Tags: typescript, for-loop, compiler-errors, null

I converted some JavaScript code to TypeScript and got an `Object possibly 'null'` error which I don't understand. It occurs within an (old) for loop even if the expression is checked for truthy. Here a reconstruction:

```
type B = {
    c: string;
}
type A = {
    b: B | null;
}

let rows: A[] = [ { b: { c: 'abc' } } ];

for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if(rows[i].b && rows[i].b.c) {      // Object possibly 'null'. (2531) at right 'rows[i].b'
        console.log('what?');
    }
}
```

So even if `rows[i].b` is checked for truthy I get the error that it could be null. I do not get the error with a `for ... of ...` loop. And neither if I assign `rows[i].b` to a variable (or const) before the check:

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeAoK6oGMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNwoC+KokUAggsmhgEa5wA+UpAVwA2Q6nRRCIwKIQD2Adzy4mAbQC6rFcihdtOKAHIAhh0wGoNC1DXUUAM1mEAFJOnFWABkpR3AHhkKeAB0khTAABbexADU0QCUbBg+dk5yiirEakEcUABkuQHpmdlBmAlISegA9FVQAPIcAFYQmNJgsnh4xBxCIIaCIgZBUE4ATACsAMwAjHG4Bml4GVkcBuyVWLKkeLKSIbLkTgby4UbAAPwGcdRJ4kmuOqyLy9k3GMQpOfk6peUbSTUoLIANbrSqYLY7PZCA5HEFXN7oOjiBzOB5pIF2Qp4cpgj6pBTZPIFNIlMraSqAkFgpIQ7a7CD7Q4GeHXMHIlCczlAA)

How could `rows[i].b` possibly become `null` on the right side of `&&` if it evaluates to true on the left side.

Comment: The compiler doesn't consider that `rows[i].b` is the same both times. That's a known common issue with TS. It's not really that it can become `null` the truthyness check is not transitive. You can just assign it to a `const item = rows[i].b` which will satisfy the compiler or use a non-null assertion for the second one `if(rows[i].b && rows[i].b!.c)`

Comment: i.e. `const b = rows[i].b; if (b && b.c) ...` will work.

Comment: Interesting case. I fully agree with @VLAZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the non-null assertion operator ! to coerce away null or undefined types:

```
for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if(rows[i].b && rows[i].b!.c) {      // <- see ! operator
      console.log('what?');
   }
}
```